# Scope of memory using linked list functions

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

I'm having a little trouble understanding an example function my professor has given as an example for linked lists. It seems that the memory allocated is not actually in the scope of main. But it seems to work. Here are the example functions:

```
#define NEW(x) (x*)malloc(sizeof(x))

NODE *make_node (void *data) {
    NODE *temp;

    temp = NEW(NODE);
    if (temp != NULL) {
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }

    return temp;
}

int insert_at_tail(ROOT *r, DATA *d) {
    NODE *temp;

    temp = make_node(d);

    if (temp == NULL)  // fail, cannot create new NODE
        return -1;

    if (r == NULL) {
        r = make_root();
        if (r == NULL) // fail, cannot create ROOT
            return -1;
    }

    (r->num)++;

    if (r->num == 1) {             // if previously the list is empty
        r->head = r->tail = temp;
    }
    else {
        r->tail->next = temp;
        r->tail = temp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It seems to me that the function insert_at_tail calls the make_node function which then returns a memory location in the function insert_at_tail. But that memory location is in the scope of that function? The memory is then assigned to linked list data. How is it that when in the main function the linked list data can still access that memory? I thought malloc was not global. Thanks for reading! Hopefully someone can help my confusion.

Comment: BTW `r = make_root();` Perhaps this does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc` is how you allocate heap memory; the allocated memory sticks around until the pointer is explicitly `free`-ed. Anyone with access to that pointer can use it until the pointer is passed to `free`.

`malloc` isn't "global" in the sense that it can return pointers to memory that isn't preallocated in global space, but that doesn't mean the memory it allocates is disposed of automatically when the scope in which `malloc` was called exits.